# Imagemagick can not find delegates library for .tiff format on mac os x mountain lion

Tags: image, macos, imagemagick, homebrew

I could not convert .tiff files to other format.

Here is some debugging output:

```
$ convert -list configure

Path: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/ImageMagick/config/configure.xml

Name          Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CC            cc
CFLAGS        -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -g -O2 -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
CODER_PATH    /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/ImageMagick/modules-Q16/coders
CONFIGURE     ./configure  '--disable-osx-universal-binary' '--without-perl' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-shared' '--disable-static' '--without-pango' '--with-included-ltdl' '--with-modules' '--disable-openmp' '--without-gslib' '--with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts' '--without-x' 'CC=cc' 'CXX=c++'
CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/etc/ImageMagick/
COPYRIGHT     Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS      -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick
CXX           c++
CXXFLAGS      -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
DEFS          -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES     bzlib freetype jpeg jng png xml zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS 'CC=cc' 'CXX=c++' --disable-deprecated --with-quantum-depth=16 --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no --with-gslib=no --with-fontpath= --with-gs-font-dir=/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts --with-pango=no --with-wmf=no --with-perl=no
DOCUMENTATION_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/share/doc/ImageMagick
EXEC-PREFIX   /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6
EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/bin
FEATURES      OpenCL
FILTER_PATH   /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/ImageMagick/modules-Q16/filters
HOST          x86_64-apple-darwin12.1.0
INCLUDE_PATH  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick
LDFLAGS       -L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/lib
LIB_VERSION   0x677
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 6,7,7,6
LIBRARY_PATH  /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/ImageMagick
LIBS          -lMagickCore -lfreetype -ljpeg -lbz2 -lz -lm -Wl,-framework,OpenCL -lm -lpthread
NAME          ImageMagick
PCFLAGS
PREFIX        /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6
QuantumDepth  16
RELEASE_DATE  2012-09-18
SHARE_PATH    /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/share/ImageMagick
SVN_REVISION  8165
TARGET_CPU    x86_64
TARGET_OS     darwin12.1.0
TARGET_VENDOR apple
VERSION       6.7.7
WEBSITE       http://www.imagemagick.org

Path: [built-in]

Name          Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NAME          ImageMagick
```

I have tried to uninstall/install libtiff, imagemagick, just won't work

```
$ brew uninstall libtiff
$ brew install imagemagick
$ brew uninstall imagemagick
$ brew install imagemagick
```

Any idea of what's wrong with my installation? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I've been having the same problem and just managed to fix it.

```
brew install libtiff
brew install imagemagick --with-libtiff
```

I tried a number of times combinations of uninstalling and reinstalling imagemagick and libtiff, but had the same results each time. I was hoping that brew would magically pick up on libtiff and link it in.

I eventually found the `with-libtiff` option by looking at the output of the command

```
brew info imagemagick
```

*Before January 30th, 2013, the option was called `--use-tiff`.*

Comment: Thanks. I've been fussing with this exact problem for the past hour.

Comment: The same trick seems to work for webp: brew install imagemagick --with-webp

Comment: Btw, to reinstall you can use: 
brew reinstall imagemagick --with-libtiff (so you don't have to uninstall first)