# Using PHP Imagick extension on Mac does not find Tiff delegate

Tags: php, macos, tiff, imagick

I've installed ImageMagick on my Mac and am trying to convert a TIFF image to a JPEG image using the PHP API that is provided by the ImageMagick extension. When I try to do that I get the following error:

```
no decode delegate for this image format
```

When I do a `convert image1.tiff image1.jpg` on the command line it works.

For some reason the PHP extension for Imagick thinks the TIFF delegate is not installed when it clearly is. Why would I get different results and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had installed both ImageMagick and the PHP ImageMagick extension php53-imagick using Homebrew. When installing them this way you don't have many options in terms of configuration. php53-imagick was  configured to use the Homebrew installation of ImageMagick.

What I did to solve the problem was download and compile the source of the Imagick PHP extension myself. The key configuration that you have to make is `./configure --with-imagick=/user/local` or wherever your ImageMagic/wand folder is.

The imagick.so will appear in the modules directory and you'll need to add it to the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a different question: There's a more convenient solution in Homebrew with the command

```
brew install libtiff
brew install imagemagick --with-libtiff
```

(see [Imagemagick can not find deletegates library for .tiff format on mac os x mountain lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943947/imagemagick-can-not-find-deletegates-library-for-tiff-format-on-mac-os-x-mounta#answer-13150641) for reference)